# mono - could not find system.web.mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, xsp

Im trying to start a test asp.net mvc application written in mono, and using XSP as the server. The problem is that im getting an exception about missing system.web.mvc on application startup.

How can i get mono to load the assembly?

Comment: This section about MVC3 might shed some light on the issue: http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support (i.e. you need to manually copy some assemblies)

Answer (score 2):

There's some info in the [Mono FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET) that might be helpful:

> *How can I run ASP.NET-based applications with Mono?*
>
> You can read our [Guide to port ASP.NET Applications with Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_ASP.NET_Applications).
>
> Additionally, this is a very good guide on porting an ASP.NET MVC
>   WebSite to Mono is a three part series blog that covers how to port an
>   ASP.NET MVC website application to Mono:
>
> - Part 1: [Installing the Software](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/01/installing-opensuse-11-2-with-mono-2-6-1-and-apache-using-text-mode-configuration-porting-to-mono-part-1-of-3/)
> - Part 2: [Setting up and Configuring MySQL](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/)
> - Part 3: [Walk through porting the ASP.NET MVC website](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/walkthrough-porting-asp-net-mvc-website-to-mono-2-6-1-and-mysql-on-linux-apache-porting-to-mono-part-3-of-3/)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I opened an MVC project that was build with system.web.mvc proper. When I did the reference was listed but there was an arrow next to it that when dropped down said the ref could not be found. Adding and removing the reference resolved that issue. However; I was using IDependancyResolver from the MS System.Web.MVC and that does not seem to be in the Mono version.